# The getter 'token' was called on null

Tags: flutter

'''final parsedExpiryTime = DateTime.parse(expiryTimeString.toString());'''

I/flutter (28078): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28078): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
I/flutter (28078): The getter 'token' was called on null.
I/flutter (28078): Receiver: null
I/flutter (28078): Tried calling: token

Comment: Please, could you provide more information, like some code? At least a question. Otherwise the answer could be `Yes, the getter 'token' was called on null`.

Comment: Can you provide more information like a piece of code to identify what causes the problem.

Comment: I am trying to convert a time to automatically log out  a user using a token generated automatically from firebase in an app i'm building and i keep getting that error thrown.

Comment: @SassyAmelet: Please update your original question with that information. Also be sure to include a sample of your relevant code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)