# What is a NoSuchMethodError and how do I fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, nosuchmethoderror, nosuchmethod

I have some code and when I run it produces an error, saying:

> NoSuchMethod: the method 'XYZ' was called on null

What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is supposed to be a canonical dupe target. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401321/canonical-q-a-for-people-that-have-problems-with-nosuchmethod-called-on-null-in. Feel free to improve Q or A.

Comment: Without knowing Flutter/Dart, I'm guessing this is their equivalent of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @TylerH that is correct

Comment: It does not really have anything to do with it, other then that person had this error too. The solution how to fix it is in the answer here.

Comment: I think title has contain `NoSuchMethodError` instead of `NoSuchMethod error`, same way as it appears in logs

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Why do I get this error?

### Example

As a real world comparison, what just happened is this conversation:

> Hey, how much gas is left in the tank of the car?

> What are you talking about, we ***don't have*** a car.

That is exactly what is happening in your program. You wanted to call a function like `_car.getGasLevel();` but *there is no car*, the variable `_car` is `null`.

Obviously, in your program it might not be a car. It could be a list or a string or anything else really.

### Technical explanation

You are trying to use a variable that is `null`. Either you have explicitly set it to `null`, or you just never set it at all, the default value is `null`.

Like any variable, it can be passed into other functions. The place where you get the error might not be the source. You will have to follow the leads from the actual `null` value to where it originally came from, to find what the problem is and what the solution might be.

`null` can have different meanings: variables not set to another value will be `null`, but sometimes null values are used by programmers intentionally to signal that there is no value. Databases have nullable fields, JSON has missing values. Missing information may indeed *be* the information itself. The variable `bool userWantsPizzaForDinner;` for example might be used for `true` when the user said yes, `false` when the user declined and it might still be `null` when the user has not yet picked something. That's not a mistake, it's intentionally used and needs to be handled accordingly.

## How do I fix it?

### Find it

Use the stack trace that came with the error message to find out exactly which line the error was on. Then set a breakpoint on that line. When the program hits the breakpoint, inspect all the values of the variables. One of them is `null`, find out which one.

### Fix it

Once you know which variable it is, find out how it ended up being `null`. Where did it come from? Was the value never set in the first place? Was the value another variable? How did *that* variable got it's value. It's like a line of breadcrumbs you can follow until you arrive at a point where you find that some variable was never set, or maybe you arrive at a point where you find that a variable was intentionally set to `null`. If it was unintentional, just fix it. Set it to the value you want it to have. If it was intentional, then you need to handle it further down in the program. Maybe you need another `if` to do something special for this case. If in doubt, you can ask the person that intentionally set it to `null` what they wanted to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

Simply the variable/function you are trying to access from the class does not exist:

```
someClass.xyz();
```

The above will give the error

```
NoSuchMethod: the method 'xyz' was called on null
```

because the class `someClass` does not exist.

The following will work fine:

```
// SomeClass created
// SomeClass has a function xyz

class SomeClass {
  SomeClass();

  void xyz() {
    print('xyz');
  }
}

void main() {

  // Create an instance of the class
  final someClass = SomeClass();

  // Access the xyz function
  someClass.xyz();
}
```

Comment: If it weren't defined, it would not have compiled in the first place. The opposite is the case: `someClass` is `null`.