# Flutter mapping data to model and using it

Tags: api, flutter, dart, model, mapping

I am very new to flutter. I am having this problem and this function is inside the Widget Build

```
Dashboard user = Dashboard();
  Future<Dashboard> setup() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    id = prefs.getInt('id');
    final response = await get('http://localhost/myproject/dashboard/user/$id');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      user = Dashboard.fromJson(data);
    }
    return user;
  }
```

My model is:

```
class Dashboard {
  int id;
  String username;
  Profile profile;

  Dashboard(
      {this.id,
      this.username,
      this.profile,
 });

  Dashboard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    username = json['username'];
    profile = json['profile'] != null ? new Profile.fromJson(json['profile']) : null;

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['username'] = this.username;
    if (this.profile != null) {
      data['profile'] = this.profile.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Profile {
  String birthday;
  int age;
  Null image;
  String gender;
  Profile(
      {this.birthday,
      this.age,
      this.image,
      this.gender});

  Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    birthday = json['birthday'];
    age = json['age'];
    image = json['image'];
    gender = json['gender'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['birthday'] = this.birthday;
    data['age'] = this.age;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['gender'] = this.gender;
    return data;
  }
}
```

My widget:

```
Container(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Column(
              children: [
                 Container(
                    child: (user.profile.age != null)
                       ? Text(
                            user.profile.age.toString(),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Open-Sans-Regular',
                            color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            )
                       : Text(
                           '36',
                           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                           style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 12.0,
                           fontFamily: 'Open-Sans-Regular',
                           color: Colors.black,
                            ),),
                       ),
```

Stacktrace :

```
The getter 'age' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: age
```

and I am getting this error:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'age' was called on null.

I initialized the class properly..
I used https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ for auto generating a model.
What I am doing wrong? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Show the code part where you are using the ``user`` value.

Comment: post the first 3-5 frames from the stacktrace

Comment: you are using the Dashboard class not the Profile class please add the correct code so we can answer you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I added the stacktrace and where i am using the user value.
The profile class is inside the dashboard class, should i make a new seperate profile class?

Answer (score 0):

This is you calling profile.age on a null profile, which you don't check for, only if that age is null.
Also, consider using a future builder depending on what exactly you're doing.