# The getter 'printable' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, exif

I am using [exif](https://pub.dev/packages/exif) plugin to identify orientation of image. But it is showing me an error following error:

```
I/flutter ( 7355): Exception in image -- NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'printable' was called on null.
```

Here is my code:

> //Method to set orientation of images   Future
> fixExifRotation(String imagePath) async {
> final originalFile = File(imagePath);
>
> ```
> List<int> imageBytes = await originalFile.readAsBytes();
>
> final originalImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
>
> final height = originalImage.height;
> final width = originalImage.width;
>
> // We'll use the exif package to read exif data
> // This is map of several exif properties
> // Let's check 'Image Orientation'
> final exifData = await readExifFromBytes(imageBytes);
>
> for (String key in exifData.keys) {
>   print("$key (${exifData[key].tagType}): ${exifData[key]}");
> }
>
> img.Image fixedImage;
> if (exifData['Image Orientation'].printable.contains('Rotated 180')) {
>     fixedImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage, 180);
> }else if (exifData['Image Orientation'].printable.contains('Horizontal (normal)')) {
>   return originalFile;
> } else{
>   return originalFile;
> }
> final fixedFile = await originalFile.writeAsBytes(img.encodeJpg(fixedImage));
> return fixedFile;   }
> ```

Issue is in

> ```
> final exifData = await readExifFromBytes(imageBytes);
> ```

Comment: `exifData['Image Orientation']` is null - the error you get says it pretty clear: `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'printable' was called on null.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention where the image is coming from

in my case I am using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and the problem was using an emulator for taking a picture. Using a real device did the trick