# i have problem with sharedPrefs this error The method 'getString' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: getString("type")

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with sharedprefs when I click on the button show this error

[The method 'getString' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getString("type")]

Comment: paste your relevant code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)