# NoSuchMethodError: ‘rating’ was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

When the form is saved, it directs to a page where one can view the data they saved. On the page where it's viewed I'm getting the following error.

`NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'rating' was called on null. Receiver: null   Tried calling: rating`

I check for null on that page `Text(contact.rating?.toString() ?? " ")` however it still shows the error.

The `rating` shows perfectly without an error after I hot reload and go to the saved form, but the error appears when the `onPress` routes to that page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Your null check does not include "contact" itself. You need to check that too.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt , yes the link was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find the null control in the incorrect place. Your contact is null. So, while the rating of the contact is null and you want to set a space string in text, it should look like this:

```
  Text(contact?.rating?.toString() ?? " ")
```

Comment: Thanks this cleared the error, however it is not showing any data on the page it directs to. It only will if I hot reload.

Comment: Ok, then the new problem is about a new question. You can share the total code of your page.