# Flutter : The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: api, flutter, dart, widget

I have this error and i don't know what's wrong

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ The following NoSuchMethodError
> was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, dependencies:
> [_InheritedProviderScope, MediaQuery], state:
> _HomeScreenState#1d9fe): The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length The relevant error-causing widget
> was HomeScreen lib\…\View\login.dart:387 When the exception was
> thrown, this was the stack
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
> #1      _HomeScreenState.build package:chroma/…/resident/home.dart:61
> #2      StatefulElement.build package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4744
> #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4627
> #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild

I want to fetch data by using api service and show it in ListBuilder

```
ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        GridView.builder(
                          gridDelegate:
                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: appProvider.homeService.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return HomeServiceList(
                              service: appProvider.homeService[index],
                              isShowDate: true,
                              callback: () {
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

and this is the class of model

```
class Service {
  Service({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.homePhoto,
    this.subServices,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  dynamic homePhoto;
  List<Service> subServices;

  factory Service.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Service(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        homePhoto: json["home_photo"],
        subServices: List<Service>.from(
            json["sub_services"].map((x) => Service.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "home_photo": homePhoto,
        "sub_services": List<dynamic>.from(subServices.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}
```

and this is the function to call it

```
class AppProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Service> _homeService;

  List<Service> get homeService => _homeService;

  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  set isLoading(bool value) {
    _isLoading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<dynamic> homeListService() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    print('Starting request');

    http.Response response =
        await http.get(Environment.home, headers: Environment.requestHeader);
    print('Completed request');
    print('respond countryList data : ${response.body}');

    Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
    var results;
    if (res['code'] == 200) {
      _homeService = [];
      res['services'].forEach((v) {
        _homeService.add(new Service.fromJson(v));
      });
      results = true;
    } else {
      results =
          FailedRequest(code: 400, message: res['massage'], status: false);
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return results;
  }
}
```

please, can anyone help me in my case !!!

Comment: Your `homeService` is null. Be sure that `appProvider.homeService`is not null.

Comment: @Akif can you tell me how to fix it please !

Comment: Can you share how the `appProvider` is being used to get the data?

Comment: @VictorEronmosele i shared it from 2 minute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @nvoigt  Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `itemCount: appProvider.homeService.length,` to :

```
itemCount: appProvider.homeService?.length ?? 0,
```

Comment: I tried that and the error disappear but i have no data return do you know the reason !!!

Comment: I think the `appProvider.homeService` is real null. you should check your code logic and make sure it's not null.

Comment: the backend developer is put data in this list so it is not null so I'm feeling nervous because I don't know the reason why it would come back null

Comment: by this line: `print('respond countryList data : ${response.body}');` can you provide the content it print out ? `_homeService` is null means that your `res['code'] == 200` is not true. please check it.