# Flutter: The getter 'image' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, rest

I'm retrieving images from API:

```
  base64FormatImage = base64FormatImage.toString();
  base64FormatImage = base64FormatImage.replaceAll('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
  base64FormatImage = base64FormatImage.replaceAll('}', '');
  base64FormatImage = base64FormatImage.replaceAll('data:image/jpegbase64,', '');
  courseImage = imageFromBase64String(base64FormatImage);
```

Images are getting retrieved, but the screen shows "The getter 'image' was called on null" for about a second or two and after a second or two, the screen shows the proper image.

Why does this happen? Why is it taking some time?

Comment: Where do you call .image?

Comment: In the CircleAvatar widget's backgroundImage property.

Comment: Can you share that code too?

Comment: CircleAvatar(
             backgroundImage: courseImage.image),   Here

Comment: Yes, in the API function definition, I'm setting the courseImage variable in the setState method itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your courseImage before using it.

```
   courseImage == null ?
      Container() :
      CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: courseImage.image)
```