# The method '*' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: *(null)

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    class _BillDetailsWidgetState extends State<BillDetailsWidget> {
  _BillDetailsWidgetState(
      {this.qtyCount,
      this.singleServicePrice,
      this.itemsTotal,
      this.totalPayablePrice});

  int qtyCount = 10;
  int singleServicePrice = 100;
  int itemsTotal;
  int totalPayablePrice = 0;

  String cartPriceTotal() {
    totalPayablePrice = qtyCount * singleServicePrice;
    return totalPayablePrice.toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Bill Details:',
                  style: kTextStyle,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Item(s) Total',
                      style: kOtherTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '249',
                      style: kOtherTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Safety & Conveyance Charges',
                      style: kOtherTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '₹ 80',
                      style: kOtherTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      cartPriceTotal(),
                      style: kOtherTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anybody help with an error!

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building BillDetailsWidget(dirty, state: _BillDetailsWidgetState#4bb59):
The method '*' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: *(null)

The relevant error-causing widget was:
BillDetailsWidget file:///C:/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/gloveson/lib/Screens/Bookings%20Page/pricing.dart:185:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _BillDetailsWidgetState.cartPriceTotal (package:gloveson/Screens/Bookings%20Page/pricing.dart:532:34)
#2      _BillDetailsWidgetState.build (package:gloveson/Screens/Bookings%20Page/pricing.dart:593:23)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4792:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:15)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 5 of 589 libraries in 1,280ms.

Comment: `totalPayablePrice = qtyCount * singleServicePrice;` either qtyCount or singleServicePrice is `null`. Could you post the rest of your code where `_BillDetailsWidgetState` is called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Er1 this is whole code! and as you can all the variables have values inside!

Comment: Are you using statefull widjet? Why do you have constructer in private class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the default values in the constructor method instead of the fields themselves. Otherwise the values will all be set to null if you are not providing values where you are creating the `_BillDetailsWidgetState` constructor. Of course multiplying `null` values results in the error you get.

```dart
class BillDetailsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BillDetailsWidgetState();
}
```

in your situation it's actually as if you were calling the State constructor like this:

```dart
class BillDetailsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BillDetailsWidgetState(
    qtyCount: null,
    singleServicePrice: null,
    itemsTotal: null,
    totalPayablePrice: null,
  );
}
```

So this fixes the issue:

```dart
  _BillDetailsWidgetState(
      {this.qtyCount = 10,
      this.singleServicePrice = 100,
      this.itemsTotal,
      this.totalPayablePrice = 0});


  int qtyCount;
  int singleServicePrice;
  int itemsTotal;
  int totalPayablePrice;
  //... omitted for brevity
```

Although you might want to rethink this solution to a `StatelessWidget` like so:

```dart
class BillDetailsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int qtyCount;
  final int singleServicePrice;

  const BillDetailsWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.qtyCount,
    @required this.singleServicePrice,
  })  : assert(qtyCount != null),
        assert(singleServicePrice != null),
        super(key: key);

  String cartPriceTotal() {
    return (qtyCount * singleServicePrice).toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ... omitted for brevity
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Since you are new on StackOverflow, feel free to accept the answer by pressing the checkmark next to it, so the question gets marked as answered for future reference for others as well.