# when i click the Button , this error " The getter 'dx' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: dx " occur in my debug consol

Tags: flutter

i wanted to select color from a dialogColor and change my apps color (appBar & Buttons)
then i use this package flutter_material_color_picker from pub dev

```
    you can see my code here:

            import 'dart:math';
    
    import 'package:animated_theme_switcher/animated_theme_switcher.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/flavors.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/helper/dbhelper.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/models/localappconfig.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/pages/home_page.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/services/createtable_services.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/widgets/common_snackbar.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/widgets/settings/settings_ui_data.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_material_color_picker/flutter_material_color_picker.dart';
    import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
    import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
    import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
    
    import '../helper/helper.dart';
    import '../sqliteProvider/userappconfig_provider.dart';
    import '../style/style.dart';
    import '../utils/uidata.dart';
    
    class SettingPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String accountName;
      final bool reception;
    
      const SettingPage({Key key, this.accountName, this.reception})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _SettingPageState createState() => _SettingPageState();
    }
    
    class _SettingPageState extends State<SettingPage> {
      ProgressDialog prDialog;
      Color _shadeColor = Colors.orange[400];
      Color _tempShadeColor;
      ColorSwatch _tempMainColor;
      ColorSwatch _mainColor = Colors.deepOrange;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initData();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // ScreenUtil.init(context, height: 896, width: 414, allowFontScaling: false);
        return ThemeSwitchingArea(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text(
                    F.companyInfo.appCompanyName,
                  ),
                ),
                body: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 30.h),
                    header(),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          widget.reception
                              ? _widgetGetDataFromSazmani(context)
                              : SizedBox(),
                          _widgetThemeColor(context),
                          _widgetFontSize(),
                          _widgetLogout(context),
                          colorChange(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> initData() async {
        prDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,
            type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: false);
        prDialog.style(
          message: 'چند لحظه صبر نمایید ',
          borderRadius: 10.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 10.0,
          insetAnimCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          progressTextStyle: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_22, FontWeight.w400),
          messageTextStyle: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_30, FontWeight.w400),
        );
      }
    
      Widget header() {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: 40.w),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Directionality(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: HomePage())),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                LineAwesomeIcons.arrow_right,
                size: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
              ),
            ),
            profileInfo(),
            themeSwitcher(),
            SizedBox(width: 40.w),
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Widget profileInfo() {
        return Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 150.h,
                width: 165.w,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55.h),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 80,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/admin.png'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40.h),
              Text(widget.accountName,
                  style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w700)),
              SizedBox(height: 60.h),
              Container(
                height: 70.h,
                width: 300.w,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                ),
                child: widgetDownloadApk(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 35.h),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _widgetGetDataFromSazmani(BuildContext context) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            _getdata(context);
          },
          child: _widgetContent("دریافت اطلاعات پذیرش", LineAwesomeIcons.upload),
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> _getdata(BuildContext context) async {
        await Helper.isOnline().then((isOnline) async {
          if (isOnline) {
            prDialog.show();
            bool result = false;
            double _netserverversion = 0;
            _netserverversion = await TableService.getVersion();
            DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();
            var map = await dbHelper.getItem('LocalAppConfig');
            LocalAppConfig appConfig = new LocalAppConfig.fromMap(map);
            if (appConfig != null && appConfig.version == 0) {
              result = await Helper.getDataSazmaniUntilEnd(_netserverversion);
            } else if (appConfig != null &&
                appConfig.version != _netserverversion) {
              await TableService.getAlterTable().then((_) async {
                result = await Helper.getDataSazmaniUntilEnd(_netserverversion);
              });
            } else {
              result = await Helper.getDataSazmaniUntilEnd(_netserverversion);
            }
            if (!result) if (prDialog.isShowing()) prDialog.hide();
          } else
            FlushbarHelper.createInformation(
                context: context,
                message: "عدم ارتباط با سرور ،مجددا اقدام نمایید.",
                title: "توجه");
        });
      }
    
      Widget widgetDownloadApk() {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: _launchURL,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 45.w),
              Text(
                "بروز رسانی ",
                style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w700),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 80.w),
              Icon(
                Icons.update_outlined,
                size: 40.w,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      _launchURL() async {
        String url = F.companyInfo.urlDownload +
            'WebApiB2BDotCore/UploadedFiles/Apk/b2bsorooshan.apk?${Random().nextInt(10000)}';
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
        }
      }
    
      Widget _widgetLogout(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Helper.onConfirmEasyDialog(
                  context,
                  'خروج',
                  'آیا از خروج از حساب کاربری اطمینان دارید؟',
                  _logout,
                  _cancel(context));
            },
            child: _widgetContent(
                "خروج از حساب کاربری", LineAwesomeIcons.alternate_sign_out),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      _logout() {
        UserAppConfigProvider configProvider = UserAppConfigProvider();
        configProvider.logOutUser(1, true).then((value) {
          Helper.onExit();
        });
      }
    
      _cancel(BuildContext context) => Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
    
      Widget _widgetThemeColor(BuildContext context) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: _openColorPicker,
            child: _widgetContent(
                " تغییر رنگ برنامه ", LineAwesomeIcons.paint_roller));
      }
    
      Widget _widgetFontSize() {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: _widgetContent(
              " تغییر سایز فونت  ", LineAwesomeIcons.alternate_pencil),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _widgetContent(String title, IconData icon) {
        return Container(
          height: 90.h,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 60.w,
          ).copyWith(
            bottom: 40.h,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 50.w,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(title,
                  style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w700)),
    
              Icon(
                icon,
                size: 30,
              ),
              // Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget themeSwitcher() {
        return ThemeSwitcher(
          builder: (context) {
            return AnimatedCrossFade(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              crossFadeState:
                  ThemeProvider.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                      ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                      : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
              firstChild: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: kLightTheme),
                child: Icon(
                  LineAwesomeIcons.sun,
                  size: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
                ),
              ),
              secondChild: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: kDarkTheme),
                child: Icon(
                  LineAwesomeIcons.moon,
                  size: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    
      ThemeData selectedColorTheme(BuildContext context) => ThemeData(
            accentColor: _shadeColor,
            appBarTheme: ThemeData.dark().appBarTheme.copyWith(color: _shadeColor),
          );
    
      void _openColorPicker() async {
        _openDialog(
          "Color picker",
          MaterialColorPicker(
            selectedColor: _shadeColor,
            onColorChange: (color) {
              _tempShadeColor = Color(color.value);
            },
            onMainColorChange: (color) {
              _tempMainColor = color;
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void _openDialog(String title, Widget content) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) {
            return AlertDialog(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              title: Text(title),
              content: content,
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('CANCEL'),
                  onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    _mainColor = _tempMainColor;
                    _shadeColor = _tempShadeColor;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    
      Widget colorChange() {
        return ThemeSwitcher(
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text(" change color "),
                onPressed: () {
                  ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(
                    theme: selectedColorTheme(context),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

when i click the " change color " Button , this error " The getter 'dx' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: dx " occur in my debug consol
Can you help me ?????

if you need to see all of the debugconsul ,you can see here:

```
[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during paint():[39;49m
The getter 'dx' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: dx

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
[38;5;248mThemeSwitchingArea[39;49m
 lib\pages\setting_page.dart
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#1      ThemeSwitcherCircleClipper._calcMaxRadius[39;49m
 package:animated_theme_switcher/…/clippers/theme_switcher_circle_clipper.dart
[38;5;244m#2      ThemeSwitcherCircleClipper.getClip[39;49m
 package:animated_theme_switcher/…/clippers/theme_switcher_circle_clipper.dart
[38;5;244m#3      ThemeSwitcherClipperBridge.getClip[39;49m
 package:animated_theme_switcher/…/clippers/theme_switcher_clipper_bridge.dart
[38;5;244m#4      _RenderCustomClip._updateClip[39;49m
 package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderClipPath#ac13c relayoutBoundary=up4[39;49m
[38;5;244mRenderObject: RenderClipPath#ac13c relayoutBoundary=up4[39;49m
    [38;5;244mneeds compositing[39;49m
    [38;5;244mparentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)[39;49m
    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=621.4)[39;49m
    [38;5;244msize: Size(411.4, 621.4)[39;49m
    [38;5;244mchild: RenderPhysicalModel#22ceb relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT[39;49m
        [38;5;244mneeds compositing[39;49m
        [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=621.4)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mlayer: PhysicalModelLayer#b27dd DETACHED[39;49m
            [38;5;244mengine layer: PhysicalShapeEngineLayer#bbffb[39;49m
            [38;5;244melevation: 0.0[39;49m
            [38;5;244mcolor: Color(0xffffffff)[39;49m
        [38;5;244msize: Size(411.4, 621.4)[39;49m
        [38;5;244melevation: 0.0[39;49m
        [38;5;244mcolor: Color(0xfffafafa)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mshadowColor: Color(0xfffafafa)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mshape: BoxShape.rectangle[39;49m
        [38;5;244mborderRadius: BorderRadius.zero[39;49m
        [38;5;244mchild: _RenderInkFeatures#f8cf2 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT[39;49m
            [38;5;244mneeds compositing[39;49m
            [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
            [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=621.4)[39;49m
            [38;5;244msize: Size(411.4, 621.4)[39;49m
            [38;5;244mchild: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#a6e7f relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT[39;49m
                [38;5;244mneeds compositing[39;49m
                [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
                [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=621.4)[39;49m
                [38;5;244msize: Size(411.4, 621.4)[39;49m
                [38;5;244mchild 1: RenderFlex#79c94 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mneeds compositing[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mparentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 80.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=541.4)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244msize: Size(411.4, 541.4)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mdirection: vertical[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mmainAxisAlignment: start[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mmainAxisSize: max[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mcrossAxisAlignment: center[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mverticalDirection: down[39;49m
                [38;5;244mchild 2: RenderConstrainedBox#f6e13 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mneeds compositing[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mparentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.appBar (can use size)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=621.4)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244msize: Size(411.4, 80.0)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244madditionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=80.0)[39;49m
                [38;5;244mchild 3: RenderStack#38874 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mparentData: offset=Offset(16.0, 605.4); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton (can use size)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=621.4)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244msize: Size(0.0, 0.0)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244malignment: centerRight[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mtextDirection: rtl[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mfit: loose[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
D/TSBackgroundFetch( 2727): - Background Fetch event received
D/TSBackgroundFetch( 2727): - finish: flutter_background_fetch
D/TSBackgroundFetch( 2727): - jobFinished
```

ThemeSwitchingArea method is here:

```
import 'clippers/theme_switcher_clipper_bridge.dart';
import 'clippers/theme_switcher_circle_clipper.dart';
import 'theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeSwitchingArea extends StatefulWidget {
  ThemeSwitchingArea({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
  })  : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  _ThemeSwitchingAreaState createState() => _ThemeSwitchingAreaState();
}

class _ThemeSwitchingAreaState extends State<ThemeSwitchingArea>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  bool _busy = false;

  //one more key to save drawer state
  final _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }

  void _afterLayout(_) {
    _oldTheme = ThemeProvider.of(context);
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: ThemeProvider.instanceOf(context).duration,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  ThemeData _oldTheme;
  Offset _switcherOffset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = ThemeProvider.of(context);
    var child;

    if (_oldTheme == null || _oldTheme == theme) {
      child = _getPage(theme);
    } else {
      var firstWidget, animWidget;

      if (ThemeProvider.instanceOf(context).reverseAnimation) {
        firstWidget = _getPage(theme);
        animWidget = RawImage(image: ThemeProvider.instanceOf(context).image);
      } else {
        firstWidget = RawImage(image: ThemeProvider.instanceOf(context).image);
        animWidget = _getPage(theme);
      }

      child = Stack(
        children: [
          firstWidget,
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller,
            child: animWidget,
            builder: (_, child) {
              return ClipPath(
                clipper: ThemeSwitcherClipperBridge(
                  clipper: ThemeProvider.instanceOf(context).clipper ??
                      const ThemeSwitcherCircleClipper(),
                  offset: _switcherOffset,
                  sizeRate: _controller.value,
                ),
                child: child,
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    return Material(child: child);
  }

  Widget _getPage(ThemeData brandTheme) {
    return Theme(
      key: _globalKey,
      data: brandTheme,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  void _getSwitcherCoordinates(switcherGlobalKey) {
    RenderBox renderObject =
        switcherGlobalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final size = renderObject.size;
    _switcherOffset = renderObject
        .localToGlobal(Offset.zero)
        .translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Widget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    var theme = ThemeProvider.of(context);
    if (!_busy && theme != _oldTheme) {
      _busy = true;
      _getSwitcherCoordinates(
          ThemeProvider.instanceOf(context).switcherGlobalKey);
      _runAnimation(theme);
    }
  }

  void _runAnimation(ThemeData theme) async {
    if (ThemeProvider.instanceOf(context).reverseAnimation) {
      await _controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
    } else {
      await _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
    }

    setState(() {
      _busy = false;
      _oldTheme = theme;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Add your ThemeSwitchingArea code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved .
we shoudl put this :

```
ThemeData newTheme = selectedColorTheme(_tempShadeColor);
              ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(
                theme: newTheme,
              );
```

after the dialog closed and check it with a boolean,like this :

```
  Widget _widgetThemeColor(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeSwitcher(builder: (context) {
      return InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            bool result = await _openDialog();
            if (result != null && result) {
              ThemeData newTheme = selectedColorTheme(_tempShadeColor);
              ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(
                theme: newTheme,
              );
            }
          },
          child: _widgetContent(
              " تغییر رنگ برنامه ", LineAwesomeIcons.paint_roller));
    });
  }
```

my Correct Code:

```
    import 'dart:math';
    
    import 'package:animated_theme_switcher/animated_theme_switcher.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/flavors.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/helper/dbhelper.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/models/localappconfig.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/pages/home_page.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/services/createtable_services.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/widgets/common_snackbar.dart';
    import 'package:appservice/widgets/settings/settings_ui_data.dart';
    import 'package:easy_dialog/easy_dialog.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_material_color_picker/flutter_material_color_picker.dart';
    import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
    import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
    import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
    
    import '../helper/helper.dart';
    import '../sqliteProvider/userappconfig_provider.dart';
    import '../style/style.dart';
    import '../utils/uidata.dart';
    
    class SettingPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final String accountName;
      final bool reception;
    
      const SettingPage({Key key, this.accountName, this.reception})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _SettingPageState createState() => _SettingPageState();
    }
    
    class _SettingPageState extends State<SettingPage> {
      ProgressDialog prDialog;
      Color _shadeColor;
      Color _tempShadeColor;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initData();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ThemeSwitchingArea(
            child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              F.companyInfo.appCompanyName,
            ),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 30.h),
              header(),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    widget.reception
                        ? _widgetGetDataFromSazmani(context)
                        : SizedBox(),
                    _widgetThemeColor(context),
                    _widgetFontSize(),
                    _widgetLogout(context),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
      }
    
      Future<void> initData() async {
        prDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,
            type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: false);
        prDialog.style(
          message: 'چند لحظه صبر نمایید ',
          borderRadius: 10.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 10.0,
          insetAnimCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          progressTextStyle: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_22, FontWeight.w400),
          messageTextStyle: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_30, FontWeight.w400),
        );
      }
    
      Widget header() {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: 40.w),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Directionality(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: HomePage())),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                LineAwesomeIcons.arrow_right,
                size: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
              ),
            ),
            profileInfo(),
            themeSwitcher(),
            SizedBox(width: 40.w),
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Widget profileInfo() {
        return Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200.h,
                  width: 175.w,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55.h),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 80,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/admin.png'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25.h),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                child: Text(widget.accountName,
                    style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w700)),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 60.h),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Container(
                  height: 70.h,
                  width: 290.w,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  child: widgetDownloadApk(),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 35.h),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _widgetGetDataFromSazmani(BuildContext context) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            _getdata(context);
          },
          child: _widgetContent("دریافت اطلاعات پذیرش", LineAwesomeIcons.upload),
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> _getdata(BuildContext context) async {
        await Helper.isOnline().then((isOnline) async {
          if (isOnline) {
            prDialog.show();
            bool result = false;
            double _netserverversion = 0;
            _netserverversion = await TableService.getVersion();
            DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper();
            var map = await dbHelper.getItem('LocalAppConfig');
            LocalAppConfig appConfig = new LocalAppConfig.fromMap(map);
            if (appConfig != null && appConfig.version == 0) {
              result = await Helper.getDataSazmaniUntilEnd(_netserverversion);
            } else if (appConfig != null &&
                appConfig.version != _netserverversion) {
              await TableService.getAlterTable().then((_) async {
                result = await Helper.getDataSazmaniUntilEnd(_netserverversion);
              });
            } else {
              result = await Helper.getDataSazmaniUntilEnd(_netserverversion);
            }
            if (!result) if (prDialog.isShowing()) prDialog.hide();
          } else
            FlushbarHelper.createInformation(
                context: context,
                message: "عدم ارتباط با سرور ،مجددا اقدام نمایید.",
                title: "توجه");
        });
      }
    
      Widget widgetDownloadApk() {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: _launchURL,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 40.w),
              Text(
                "بروز رسانی ",
                style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w700),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 80.w),
              Icon(
                Icons.update_outlined,
                size: 40.w,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      _launchURL() async {
        String url = F.companyInfo.urlDownload +
            'WebApiB2BDotCore/UploadedFiles/Apk/b2bsorooshan.apk?${Random().nextInt(10000)}';
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
        }
      }
    
      Widget _widgetLogout(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            return EasyDialog(
                width: ScreenUtil.screenWidthDp * 0.75,
                height: ScreenUtil.screenHeightDp * 0.25,
                closeButton: false,
                title: Text(
                  'خروج',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_30, FontWeight.bold),
                  textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                ),
                description: Text(
                  'آیا از خروج از حساب کاربری اطمینان دارید؟',
                  textScaleFactor: 1.1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w500),
                ),
                contentList: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.h,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton.icon(
                        elevation: 15,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.cancel,
                          color: WHITE,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          'خیر',
                          style:
                              Style.styleTextWhite(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        onPressed: () => _cancel(context),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 50.w,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton.icon(
                        elevation: 15,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle,
                          color: WHITE,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          'بله',
                          style:
                              Style.styleTextWhite(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        onPressed: () => _logout(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.h,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]).show(context);
          },
          child: _widgetContent(
              "خروج از حساب کاربری", LineAwesomeIcons.alternate_sign_out),
        );
      }
    
      _logout() {
        UserAppConfigProvider configProvider = UserAppConfigProvider();
        configProvider.logOutUser(1, true).then((value) {
          Helper.onExit();
        });
      }
    
      _cancel(BuildContext context) => Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
    
      Widget _widgetThemeColor(BuildContext context) {
        return ThemeSwitcher(builder: (context) {
          return InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                bool result = await _openDialog();
                if (result != null && result) {
                  ThemeData newTheme = selectedColorTheme(_tempShadeColor);
                  ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(
                    theme: newTheme,
                  );
                }
              },
              child: _widgetContent(
                  " تغییر رنگ برنامه ", LineAwesomeIcons.paint_roller));
        });
      }
    
      Widget _widgetFontSize() {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: _widgetContent(
              " تغییر سایز فونت  ", LineAwesomeIcons.alternate_pencil),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _widgetContent(String title, IconData icon) {
        return Container(
          height: 90.h,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 80.w,
          ).copyWith(
            bottom: 40.h,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 50.w,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(title,
                  style: Style.styleTextBlack(TEXT_SIZE_24, FontWeight.w700)),
              Icon(
                icon,
                size: 27,
              ),
              // Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget themeSwitcher() {
        return ThemeSwitcher(
          builder: (context) {
            return AnimatedCrossFade(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              crossFadeState:
                  ThemeProvider.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                      ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                      : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
              firstChild: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: kLightTheme),
                child: Icon(
                  LineAwesomeIcons.sun,
                  size: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
                ),
              ),
              secondChild: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    ThemeSwitcher.of(context).changeTheme(theme: kDarkTheme),
                child: Icon(
                  LineAwesomeIcons.moon,
                  size: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    
      ThemeData selectedColorTheme(Color newColor) {
        return ThemeData(
            // accentColor: newColor,
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: newColor),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
            primaryColor: newColor,
            brightness: Theme.of(context).brightness,
            inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: newColor, width: 1),
              ),
            )
            // dialogBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
            // dialogTheme: DialogTheme(backgroundColor:  Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
            //  inputDecorationTheme: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    
            //     borderSide:  BorderSide(color: newColor, width: 1),
            //   ))
            // InputDecorationTheme(enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            //   borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            //   borderSide:  BorderSide(color: newColor, width: 1),
            // ))
    
            );
      }
    
      Future<bool> _openDialog() async {
        bool result = await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) {
            return AlertDialog(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              title: Text("Color picker"),
              content: MaterialColorPicker(
                selectedColor: _shadeColor,
                onColorChange: (color) {
                  // color =Colors.red;
                  _tempShadeColor = Color(color.value);
                },
                // onMainColorChange: (color) {
                //   _tempMainColor = Color(color.value);
                // },4294924066
                // 4294924066
              ),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('CANCEL'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                    child: Text('submit'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true)
                    //  Navigator.of(context).pop,
                    ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
        return result;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Future function is returning void value. See if data is passing after the button event