# Flutter showing The method '[]' was called on null. on Listbuilder

Tags: flutter

I am fetching data from an api and showing in ListView builder But its showing error

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool show = false;
  var map = {};
  @override
  void initState() {
    dosomestuff();

  }
  Future<List> dosomestuff() async {
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      'http://retailapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/menu/2112',
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(res.body);

    if (map['description'] == "Success") {
      print('show kr ');
      print(map["Categories"].length);
      print(map["Categories"]);
      setState(() {
        show = true;
      });
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: show
          ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: map["Categories"].length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            width: 80.0,
            child: Text(map["Categories"][index]['Name'])
          );
        },
      ) : Container(),

    );
  }
}
```

Its showing error `The method '[]' was called on null`. But when i print the values in state function the its priting values and all things are working but when ill show in ListBuilder then its showing that error.

You can see i print the values in function

```
  print(map["Categories"].length);
  print(map["Categories"]);
```

And its printing values all things fine.

[image]

You can see in image its printing the length and arrays fine so its not null when i use in widget its saying length is called on null -_-

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please post logs as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this I might have mistyped the parentheses.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;
      bool show = false;
      var map = {};
      List<dynamic>  getCategory;

   @override
    void initState() {
     dosomestuff();

      }
 Future<List> dosomestuff() async {
       await http.get(
       'http://retailapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/menu/2112',
        ).then((result){
       http.Response res=result;
       Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(res.body);

       if (map['description'] == "Success") {       
      if(map["Categories"].length>0){
         setState(() {
           show = true;
      getCategory=map["Categories"];
        });
        }
     }
   }

   });






 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(

     title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
   body: show
      ? ListView.builder(
    itemCount: getCategory.length,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        width: 80.0,
        child: Text(getCategory[index]['Name'])
      );
    },
    ) : Container(),

    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: What do you think this does differently?

Answer (score 1):

You have two declarations of `map`. One in class scope the other one in `dosomestuff` method. Remove the declaration of `map` in `dosomestuff` method and just assign the value of `json.decode(res.body)` to the `map` in class scope.
Instead of:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(res.body);
```

use:

```
map = json.decode(res.body);
```