# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'insert' was called on null. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I modified the basic `sqlLite` example to fit a more dynamic list. But its probably not the best method of doing it. Anyway the `Database` code looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';
import 'Entry.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class Database_ {

  Future<Database> database ;

  void openDBFunction() async {
    var databasesPath  = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'Journal Entries.db');
    database = openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
          await db.execute(
              "CREATE TABLE entries( _entry TEXT, _date TEXT)"
          );
    });
  }

  Future<void> insertEntry(Entry entry) async {
    final Database db = await database;
    await db.insert(
      'entry',
      entry.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }
  Future<List<Entry>> entries() async {
    final Database db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('entries');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Entry(
        maps[i]["_entry"],
        maps[i]["_date"],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

the `main.dart` looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:slide_journal/MainPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:slide_journal/Database_.dart';

main()async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Database_().openDBFunction();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

and then this is the input page:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:slide_journal/Database_.dart';
import 'package:slide_journal/Entry.dart';
import 'List_of_Entries.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget{
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(30))),
        title: Text("Home"),
        toolbarHeight: 50,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions:<Widget> [IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt_sharp),
          onPressed: () =>{
            Navigator.push(context, (MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ListOfEntries())))
          },
        ),
        ]
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: Text("Trisha is baby", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

      body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 600,
                  width: 350,
                  child: TextField(
                    enabled: true,
                    controller: _controller,
                    enableSuggestions: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Use text, emojis...",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => {
                          addEntry(_controller.toString(), "DateTime.now().toString()"),
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.send_outlined),
                      ),
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    maxLength: 100,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
  void addEntry(String entry_, String date_)async {
    final entry = Entry(
        entry_,
        date_
    );
    Database_().insertEntry(entry);

  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'insert' was called on null.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database is not intialized in your app. Do as below

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static String tableName = 'entries';

  static late Database _database;

  static Future<Database> get database async {
    final databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final status = await databaseExists(databasePath);
    if (!status) {
      _database = await openDatabase(join(databasePath, 'notes_database.db'),
          onCreate: (database, version) {
        return database.execute(
              "CREATE TABLE entries( _entry TEXT, _date TEXT)"
          );
      }, version: 1);
    }
    return _database;
  }


  static Future<bool> insertDb(Model yourModel) async {
    final db = await database;
    try {
      await db.insert(your insert cmd);
    } on Error {
      throw Error();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped but now  I'm getting this error:

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: entry (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Comment: You are suppose to replace my data with your details. Like your table name

Comment: I did do that. Its giving me this: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: entry (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO entry (_entry, _date) VALUES (?, ?)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO entry (_entry, _date) VALUES (?, ?)'

Answer (score 0):

`database` is not initialized. It has to be initialized before you can turn objects into it.