# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showNotificationDaily' was called on null in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I'm trying to implement local notifications but I'm facing the **NoSuchMethodError**, I have debugged the code and find the issue but didn't find the correct solution for it.
I have created the notification manager class I'm calling it like this in AddNotification.dart Stateful class

```
 final NotificationManager manager;
  const AddNotification(this.manager);
```

then call it like this in its State class:

```
widget.manager.showNotificationDaily(1, "Asar", "isNotification", hour, minute);
```

and in the previous class from where AddNotification is called is I have sent a Notification manager object like this.

```
class AllSurah extends StatefulWidget {
  NotificationManager manager;
  @override
  _AllSurahState createState() => _AllSurahState();
}
    Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddNotification(widget.manager)),
                  );
```

I have debugged the code and find that the manager is passing null from the previous class from where the NotificationManger object is passed. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the below code:

```
 NotificationManager manager = new NotificationManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you're not passing the variable to the object. Rather the problem is that the `manager` variable is null at the moment you're calling `showNotificationDaily` on it, which throws the Exception you're seeing.

You can avoid **Null Exceptions** by using the *Null Aware Operator* ( **?** ), like this:

```
widget.manager?.showNotificationDaily(1, "Asar", "isNotification", hour, minute);
```

But that will only avoid an `Exception` being thrown. You should really investigate why this variable is being passed as `null`