# The method 'substring' was called on null & Receiver: null Tried calling: substring(0, 1) see also flutter doc

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, chat

Hi im trying to code a simple app with Dart and Firebase but im facing a problem.
im getting this error => The method 'substring' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: substring(0, 1)

i have tried so many ways but it did not work. i wish you can help me

and this is my code(it's not the whole code)

```
import 'package:firebase_auth_ui/firebase_auth_ui.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth_ui/providers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as FirebaseAuth;
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'package:the_right_one/firebase.utils/firebase_utils.dart';
import 'package:the_right_one/screen/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:the_right_one/utils/utils.dart';

import 'const/const.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(
    app: app,
  )));
  // runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp(app: app,)));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  FirebaseApp app;

  MyApp({this.app});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/register':
            return PageTransition(
                child: RegisterScreen(
                  app: app,
                  user: FirebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser ?? null,
                ),
                type: PageTransitionType.fade,
                settings: settings);
            break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
        app: app,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: sadly no. i have tried many ways. do you have discord to look at my code or can i send you my whole code? thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.