# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null in Flutter using Dart with Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: get("legpressReps")"

This is my calender log class which accesses documents which based on a specific sport name and time that is entered.

```
class CalendarLog {
 getCalendarLog(String sportName, Timestamp date) {
 return FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
    .where('sport', isEqualTo: sportName)
    .get();
}
}
```

This is where I override the initState to access the documents which have a sport name 'weightlifting' and date set to 10-27-2021

```
bool calendarLogFlag = false;
var calendarLogs;
@override
void initState(){
super.initState();

DateTime date1 = DateTime.utc(2021, 10, 27);
Timestamp date = Timestamp.fromDate(date1);
CalendarLog().getCalendarLog('weightlifting', date).then((QuerySnapshot docs){
if(docs.docs.isNotEmpty){
  calendarLogFlag  = true;
  calendarLogs = docs.docs[0];
}
});
```

When we try to display a data field in the home page, this is how we are trying to access it:

```
label: Text(calendarLogs.get('legPressReps') ?? 0),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

Your code in the `.then()` block runs asyncronously. It might not have completed when you call `calendarLogs.get('legPressReps')` and if it hasn't, then `calendarLogs` is still `null`.

A quick fix would be `calendarLog?.get('legPressReps')`, but then you need some state management with `setState` to make sure you notify your builder about the fact that it changed to something that is not null.

Look into [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it) to find out how to handle asyncronous behaviour properly in your application.

Answer (score -1):

Try change this line :

```
label: Text(calendarLogs.get('legPressReps') ?? 0),
```

with this line:

```
label: Text(calendarLogs["legPressReps"]) ?? 0),
```

If it does not work, try to also change this line :

```
calendarLogs = docs.docs[0];
```

with this line:

```
calendarLogs = docs.docs[0].data();
```

If still does not work, you will need to share your code for this `getCalendarLog` and a snapshot from your database

see more in this [link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) on how `QuerySnapshot`  work.

Comment: Please do not just fire of a bunch of wild guesses.