# flutter - Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'call'

Tags: flutter, dart

I received this error when I run the project. I am using a JSON API from
https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yummly2.

This is error I got,
**Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'call'
Dynamic call of object has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonMap'
Arguments: ["name"]**

I don't understand why I can get the error, because there are no red lines on my code.

api_recipe.dart

```
import 'package:deliciouso/model/recipe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:deliciouso/model/api_recipe.dart';

class ApiRecipe {


  static Future<List<Recipe>> getRecipe() async {
    var uri = Uri.https('yummly2.p.rapidapi.com', '/feeds/list',
        {"start": "0", "limit": "18", "tag": "list.recipe.popular"});

    final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "659d1b868cmsh981c45e6fe4147fp12524fjsna4689c3a42f3",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "yummly2.p.rapidapi.com",     
      "useQueryString": "true"
    });

    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    List _temp = [];

    for(var i in data['feed']){
      _temp.add(i['content']['details']);
    }
    return Recipe.recipeFromSnapshot(_temp);
    
  }
}
```

recipe.dart

```
  final String name;
  final String img;
  final double rating;
  final String time;

  Recipe(
      {required this.name,
      required this.img,
      required this.rating,
      required this.time});

  factory Recipe.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Recipe(
        name: json('name') as String,
        img: json('img')[0]['hostedLargeURL'] as String,
        rating: json('rating') as double,
        time: json('time') as String);
  }

  static List<Recipe> recipeFromSnapshot(List snapshot) {
    return snapshot.map((data) {
      return Recipe.fromJson(data);
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
   
    return 'Recipe {name: $name, img: $img, rating: $rating, time: $time}';
  }
}
```

recipe_card.dart

```
class RecipeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String rating;
  final String cookTime;
  final String url;

  const RecipeCard(
      {required this.title,
      required this.rating,
      required this.cookTime,
      required this.url});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22, vertical: 10),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 250,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              offset: Offset(0.0, 10.0),
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              spreadRadius: -6.0),
        ],
        image: DecorationImage(
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.35), BlendMode.multiply),
            image: NetworkImage(url),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              child: Text(title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          Align(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.stars,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        size: 18,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 7,
                      ),
                      Text(rating),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.schedule,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        size: 18,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 7,
                      ),
                      Text(cookTime),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:deliciouso/screens/widget/recipe_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:deliciouso/model/recipe.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late List<Recipe> _recipe;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getRecipe();
  }

  Future<void> getRecipe() async {
    _recipe = await ApiRecipe.getRecipe();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.restaurant_menu),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text('Food Recipes')
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: _isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _recipe.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return RecipeCard(
                    title: _recipe[index].name,
                    cookTime: _recipe[index].time,
                    rating: _recipe[index].rating.toString(),
                    url: _recipe[index].img,
                  );
                },
              ));
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Delicioso',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @nvoigt I don't believe that dupe target is appropriate here. The OP is using `()` instead of `[]` when trying to access their `Map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Recipe.fromJson` method has some incorrect syntax. When accessing the members of a `Map`, use the `[]` operator. Do not use `()` as you are doing currently.

```dart
factory Recipe.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Recipe(
        name: json['name'] as String,
        img: json['img'][0]['hostedLargeURL'] as String,
        rating: json['rating'] as double,
        time: json['time'] as String);
}
```

`()` will try to invoke the `call` method of an object, which your object does not have, which is why you get the error "call of object has no instance method 'call'"

Comment: now i got new error like this **Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: null
Arguments: [0]**

Comment: @HisyamHaryo For that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Check to make sure your json has an `img` field and that you've spelled it correctly.

Comment: oh dear, thank you very much