# I tried to make reusable widget but "The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

H3ll0, everyone. I'm new to this. I use Flutter on Android Studio. I wanna ask a question about reusable widget and its correlation to the API

I tried to make this and I tried to called it under a Container with width of MediaQuery size width

```
class VarianPenjualan extends StatefulWidget {
  final productDetail;

  const VarianPenjualan({Key? key, this.productDetail}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VarianPenjualanState createState() => _VarianPenjualanState();
}

class _VarianPenjualanState extends State<VarianPenjualan> {
  List arrList = [];
  var listData = [];
  bool isChecked = false;
  int _counter = 0;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getProductDetailData(widget.productDetail['id']);
    getProduct();
  }

  getProductDetailData(id) async {
    var respon = await ApiService().getProductDetail({"id": id});

    if (respon['status'] == 200) {
      if (!this.mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        listData.addAll([respon['data']]);
      });
    }
  }

  getProduct() async {
    var respon = await ApiService().getProduct({"limit": 6, "page": 1});

    if (respon['status'] == 200) {
      if (!this.mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        arrList.addAll(respon['data']['productAsgrosList']);
      });
    }
  }

  _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (_counter > 0) {
        _counter--;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment:
      MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment:
      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Checkbox(
            value: isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
              setState(() {
                isChecked = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
        ), // CheckBox
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:
            MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment:
            CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Kemasan",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 5.0),
                child:
                Text("${(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['kemasan'])}"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ), // Kemasan
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:
            MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment:
            CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Harga",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 5.0),
                child: Text("${GlobalFunctions().rupiah(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['price'])}"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ), // Harga
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:
            MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment:
            CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Stok",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Color(0xff000000)),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 5.0),
                child: Text("${(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['stock'])}"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ), // Stok
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 120,
                height: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF31708F),
                  borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(3),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment:
                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment:
                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          _decrementCounter();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          alignment:
                          Alignment.center,
                          // padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          //     right: 10),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.remove,
                            color: Color(
                                0xffFFFFFF),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ), // Minus
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Text(
                        '$_counter',
                        textAlign:
                        TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color:
                            Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Quantity Number
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          _incrementCounter();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          alignment:
                          Alignment.center,
                          // padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          //     right: 10),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Color(
                                0xffFFFFFF),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ), // Add
                  ],
                ),
              ), // Counter
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    7, 4, 7, 4),
                width: 120,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 0.5,
                        color:
                        Color(0xff31708F)),
                    borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                            2))),
                child: Text("${GlobalFunctions().rupiah(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['price'] * _counter)}"),
              ), // Total Harga
            ],
          ),
        ), // Quantity Counter
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
      ],
    ); // varian 1
  }
}
```

but " The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling:  " appeared

I tried to understand the answers from the similiar question, but i can't understand it. Can you guys help me?

Comment: check null for array listData

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i'm sorry, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add loading widget since the listData fetch all response and then build the widget:

```
    class _VarianPenjualanState extends State<VarianPenjualan> {
      List arrList = [];
      var listData = [];
      bool isChecked = false;
      int _counter = 0;

      bool isLoaded = false;

      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getProductDetailData(widget.productDetail['id']);
        getProduct();
      }

      getProductDetailData(id) async {
        var respon = await ApiService().getProductDetail({"id": id});

        if (respon['status'] == 200) {
          if (!this.mounted) return;
          setState(() {
            listData.addAll([respon['data']]);
            isLoaded = true;
          });
        }
      }

      getProduct() async {
        var respon = await ApiService().getProduct({"limit": 6, "page": 1});

        if (respon['status'] == 200) {
          if (!this.mounted) return;
          setState(() {
            arrList.addAll(respon['data']['productAsgrosList']);
          });
        }
      }

      _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          _counter++;
        });
      }

      _decrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          if (_counter > 0) {
            _counter--;
          }
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return isLoaded
            ? listData.length != 0
                ? Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Checkbox(
                          value: isChecked,
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              isChecked = value!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ), // CheckBox
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Kemasan",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xff000000)),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                              child: Text(
                                  "${(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['kemasan'])}"),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ), // Kemasan
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Harga",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xff000000)),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                              child: Text(
                                  "${GlobalFunctions().rupiah(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['price'])}"),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ), // Harga
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Stok",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xff000000)),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                              child:
                                  Text("${(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['stock'])}"),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ), // Stok
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 120,
                              height: 30,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xFF31708F),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        _decrementCounter();
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        //     right: 10),
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.remove,
                                          color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ), // Minus
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Text(
                                      '$_counter',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // Quantity Number
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        _incrementCounter();
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        //     right: 10),
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.add,
                                          color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ), // Add
                                ],
                              ),
                            ), // Counter
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(7, 4, 7, 4),
                              width: 120,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      width: 0.5, color: Color(0xff31708F)),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))),
                              child: Text(
                                  "${GlobalFunctions().rupiah(listData[0]['packaging'][0]['price'] * _counter)}"),
                            ), // Total Harga
                          ],
                        ),
                      ), // Quantity Counter
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: Text('No Data'),
                  )
            : CircularProgressIndicator(); // varian 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, it makes me happy that the infinite error red bar is gone now.
but the CircularProgressIndicator is always running and the data is not loaded yet.
is there any missing code? i've waited for 5 min

Comment: Replcae listData.length != 0 instead of listData.isNotEmpty

Comment: thx a lot, friend. really appreciate that. hope you have good day