# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toDate())

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, time

**Hi When I get the data from Firebase, it gives an error. The codes are as follows. where do you think i am going wrong**

```
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "aciklama": aciklama,
      "fiyat": fiyat,
      "aciklamaDate": aciklamaDate ?? FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      "kim": kim,
    };
  }

  Vergi.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : aciklama = snapshot["aciklama"],
        fiyat = snapshot["fiyat"],
        aciklamaDate = snapshot["aciklamaDate"].toDate(),
        kim = snapshot["kim"];
```

**codes in data list:**

```
Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Spacer(),
                                        Text(
                                          DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(
                                            data["aciklamaDate"].toDate()
                                          ),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black
                                                .withOpacity(0.5),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: hi @nvoigt Thank you. But I couldn't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either>

```
snapshot["aciklamaDate"].toDate()
```

or

```
data["aciklamaDate"].toDate()
```

calls `toDate()` on a null value.

Since you have the full stacktrace, you should be able to say which on it is.

That means that in the map, "aciklamaDate" does not exist. Why? Well, that is for you to find out.

Comment: `"aciklamaDate": aciklamaDate ?? FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), ` If the user does not enter a date in the section, it automatically assigns a date from the system. Is the problem from there?

Comment: No... it's the part where you get it back and it's null.