# The method '>=' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: >=(0.0), until I remove and replace

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a flutter program which is reading values from Cloud Firestore and stores them into variables. I can normally show their value with Text(), or change them.
Now I wanted to make a Color display with a simple if statement. So if the Firestore value for example is bigger than 1 (>1), the color shall be blue. If it is smaller, then red.

But for some reason, when opening the page, it gives me this error: The method '>=' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: >=(0.0)

But if I simply remove my if code, start the program again, and then add it again, it works just fine. It seems that it has a problem with the start values, but how do I fix that?

```
                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('Digitaluhr')
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                              int itemCount =
                                  snapshot.data.docs.length; //Dokumentlänge
                              itemCount--; //-1 weil Index
                              Luftguete = snapshot.data.docs[itemCount]
                                  ['Luftgüte']; //Luftgüte Wert zum Verarbeiten
                              return ListTile(

if (Luftguete > 2.00 && Luftguete <= 3.00)
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      width: 40, color: Colors.yellow),
                                ),
                                child: Text('Mäßig',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        height: 0.00001,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow)),
                              ),

                            if (Luftguete > 3.00 && Luftguete <= 4.00)
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      width: 40, color: Colors.orange),
                                ),
                                child: Text('Schlecht',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        height: 0.00001,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange)),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is guesswork, because you did not actually post the code in question... but `Luftguete` seems to be not a local variable, but probably in your state. So... before your StreamBuilder (I guess, not in your code either) fires the first time, it is *null*. And you probably access it somewhere else. If you make `Luftguete` a *local* variable, you will find where else you access it. Because you will get compiler errors :)

Or, maybe you have a data point where `snapshot.data.docs[itemCount]['Luftgüte']` is simply null. We don't know your data. You would need to check that.

See also: [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick response. Yes, you guessed right. Luftguete is a global variable which reads the value. But the thing is, if I remove my if commands, it shows me all data correctly and monitors it. But if I open the page with the if commands activated, the error occurs. I have to remove the ifs, press STRG+S, then place them again, again STRG+S and then I can see them.