# The method 'getString' was called on null

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am currently working on an editable profile. But as I run the project I receive the following error:

> The method 'getString' was called on null. Receiver: null

Tried calling: `getString("aresraa")`

How to proceed forward?

```
class UserPreferences {
  static  SharedPreferences _preferences;
  static const _keyUser = 'aresraa';
  static const myUser = User(
    imagePath:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554151228-14d9def656e4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=333&q=80',
    name: 'Aresrana',
   
    isDarkMode: false,
  );

  static Future init() async =>
      _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


  static Future setUser(User user) async {
    final json = jsonEncode(user.toJson());

    await _preferences.setString(_keyUser, json);
  }

  static User getUser() {
    final json = _preferences.getString(_keyUser);

    return json == null ? myUser : User.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
  }
}
```

Comment: is _preferences maybe null? can you debug?

Comment: Can check on AVD if the SharedPreferences already saved?

Comment: Why is this even compiling? Are you running an outdated version of Dart?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `_preferences` is null and get the instance again. Shared Preferences gives you the singleton instance.

```
static User getUser() {
  _preferences ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final json = _preferences.getString(_keyUser);
  return json == null ? myUser : User.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to find out is to do this exercises, 60 min and you will understand whole problem. -> https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety