# i'm using google maps and i don't know the solution of this error

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, dart-null-safety

what is the solution of this error?

> {geocoded_waypoints: [{}, {}], routes: [], status: ZERO_RESULTS}
> E/flutter (27947): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
> E/flutter (27947): Receiver: null

Comment: You are getting null somepoint instead of list, Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.