# Flutter error: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My Flutter app shows the following **error**:

> E/flutter (13058): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
> E/flutter (13058): Receiver: null
> E/flutter (13058): Tried calling:

This **error** points to **3** different pieces of code which will be listed below:

**user.dart:**

```
    UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    _name = snapshot.data()[NAME];
      _email = snapshot.data()[EMAIL];
    _id = snapshot.data()[ID];
    _phone = snapshot.data()[PHONE];
    _token = snapshot.data()[TOKEN];
    _photo = snapshot.data()[TOKEN];
    _votes = snapshot.data()[VOTES];
    _trips = snapshot.data()[TRIPS];
    _rating = snapshot.data()[RATING];
  }
```

**user.dart:**

```
    Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id) =>
      firebaseFiretore.collection(collection).doc(id).get().then((doc) {
        return UserModel.fromSnapshot(doc);
      });
```

**user.dart:**

```
    _onStateChanged(User firebaseUser) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    } else {
      _user = firebaseUser;
      await prefs.setString("id", firebaseUser.uid);

      _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(user.uid).then((value) {
        _status = Status.Authenticated;
        return value;
      });
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

How do I solve this error? If any further information required, do let me know.

Comment: snapshot.data() is null.

Comment: `if(snapshot.data() != null) {_name = snapshot.data()[NAME];` ..... and so one`}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Make return type `nullable`

```
Future<UserModel?> getUserById(String id) =>
      firebaseFiretore.collection(collection).doc(id).get().then((doc) {
        if(doc.exist) {
          return null;
        }
        return UserModel.fromSnapshot(doc);
      });
```